# Не показывает сообщения из другого потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Имеется клиент-серверный консольный чатик.

При выборе между клиентом и сервером выбираем сервер `S`. Далее запускается сервер, но при  вводе в строке `kill` не срабатывает сообщение из условия. Почему не срабатывает и как можно исправить?

Код сервера:

```
package server;

import main.Const;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {

    private List<Connection> connections =
            Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Connection>());
    private ServerSocket server;
    private BufferedReader in_server;
    private PrintWriter out_server;

    public Server() {
        try {

            server = new ServerSocket(Const.Port);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String str_s = "";
                    while(true) {
                        System.out.println("Starting thread 2");
                        str_s = scanner.nextLine();
                        if (str_s == "kill") {
                            System.out.println("Kill AAAAAlll");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            while(true) {
                Socket socket = server.accept();

                Connection con = new Connection(socket);
                connections.add(con);

                con.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeAll();
        }
    }

    private void closeAll() {
        try {
            server.close();

            synchronized (connections) {
                Iterator<Connection> iter = connections.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    ((Connection) iter.next()).close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Connection extends Thread {

        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;
        private Socket socket;

        private String name = "";

        public Connection(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
            try {

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error while connection.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                name = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(name + " came now ");
                synchronized (connections) {
                    Iterator<Connection> iter = connections.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        ((Connection) iter.next()).out.println(name + " came now ");
                    }
                }

                String str = "";
                while (true) {
                    str = in.readLine();
                    if (str.equals("exit")) break;
                    System.out.println(name + " : " + str);
                    synchronized ( connections ) {
                        Iterator<Connection> iter = connections.iterator();
                        while (iter.hasNext()) {
                            ((Connection) iter.next()).out.println(name + " : " + str);
                        }
                    }
                }

                synchronized (connections) {
                    Iterator<Connection> iter = connections.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        ((Connection) iter.next()).out.println(name + " has left ");
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                close();
            }
        }

        private void close(){
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Something wrong while close connections");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Строки нельзя так сравнивать: `str_s == "kill"`. Только через `equals` вот так: `str_s.equals("kill")`.

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо. Глупость сделал.